# Enable clicks triggered in jQuery, but not mouse/touch

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I use `.disabled` on elements I want to restrict clicks on, but came across an issue, as I want to be able to trigger click on these from jQuery and am not sure how to achieve both. I tried css `pointer-events: none;` , but that is not supported in some of the browsers I need to support.

Here is current disabling code:

```
$('.disabled').click(false);
```

Comment: Can you please add html and script? Or create a fiddle?

Comment: you cannot disable clicks in general and yet enable them by trigger. You need to check the class in every click manually than

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable, some elements `click` event handler, you can check if the element is having `disabled` class.

```
$('mySelector').click(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('disabled')) {
        return false; // Prevent click 
    }

    // Event handler code here
    ....
});
```

CSS:

```
.disabled {
    opacity: .5;
    cursor: default;
}
```

This way, you don't have to `unbind` and then again `bind` events.

Answer (score 0):

Use return false or [preventDefault](http://api.jquery.com/preventDefault):

```
$('.disabled').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //or
    //return false;
});
```

But if this is a button or input element then you can use html attribute disabled like below:

```
<input class="disabled" type="text" disabled="disabled" />
```